# Plotly: plotting a 3D mesh with a flat part with Y=0 doesn't show in figure

Tags: python, 3d, plotly, mesh

I tried to plot a 3D mesh made up of triangle in plotly. It is an antenna that has base (We can see it no problem) but we can't render the flat antenna where all of its point are located at 0.

```py
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

triangleIn3D = ... # A numpy matrix with all the coordinates for each RWG triangle

dat = []

for coord in range(triangleIn3D.shape[0]):    
    dat.append(go.Mesh3d(x=triangleIn3D[coord,:3, 0], y=triangleIn3D[coord,:3, 1], z=triangleIn3D[coord,:3, 2], color='lightpink',contour_width=16, contour_color="#101010", contour_show=True))
    dat.append(go.Mesh3d(x=triangleIn3D[coord,3:, 0], y=triangleIn3D[coord,3:, 1], z=triangleIn3D[coord,3:, 2], color='lightpink', opacity=0.50))


fig = go.Figure(data=dat)
fig.show()
```

[image: Missing Antenna]

So we were wondering if it's due to how plotly handles lights and reflexion. Tried to find some explanation in the doc but without any success.

Changing the light, changing the color, opacity, mesh, facecolor

Answer (score 0):

Meshes are for displaying surfaces. If you only have points on a line, that is not a surface. If you want to show it, you need to add it as a line plot using a separate trace.